# How to set popover to fullscreen in ios

Tags: ios, fullscreen, uipopovercontroller

I  want to make a popover to fullscreen

```
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:cameraUI];
[_popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view             
               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUnknown animated:YES];
```

who know how to do it in ios7/ios8

Comment: what is the actual problem you have?

Comment: If you want full screen,then why don't you use presentViewController for fullscreen...

Comment: Because I need to present UIImagePickerController for choosing photo from Photo Library

Comment: My problem is how to set popover to fullscreen in ipad

Answer (score 0):

well anyway if your problem is it's not working on a phone then add a category like this

```
@interface UIPopoverController (phone)
+ (BOOL)_popoversDisabled;
@end

@implementation UIPopoverController (phone)
+ (BOOL)_popoversDisabled {
    return NO;
}
@end
```

then doing a popover like this seems just fine.  so again, not sure what your actual problem is (if any)

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType =
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage,nil];
imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

UIPopoverController * popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUnknown animated:YES];
```

Comment: My problem is how to set popover to fullscreen in ipad